# How can I listen to a RactiveJS custom component?

Tags: javascript, events, ractivejs

I have a `HTML` file (let's call it `TreeUser.html`) using a `Ractive` custom [component](http://docs.ractivejs.org/edge/components) (let's call it Tree in my example). This Tree is used by TreeUser as follows:

**Tree.js**

```
...
var Tree = Ractive.extend({ 
    template : Tree.html,

    onrender : function() {
        select : function(event) {
            this.set("selected", event.context);
            this.fire("selected", event.context)
        }
    })
});

return Tree;
```

})

**TreeUser.html**

```
<Tree>
    ....
</Tree>
```

**TreeUser.js**

```
var TreeUser = Ractive.extend({
    ...

    components : {
        Tree : Tree
    },

    onrender : function() {
        // Here, I'd like to observe to Tree's fire. This does not work:
        this.components.Tree.prototype.observe("selected", function(item){
            // Do something
        })
    },  

return TreeUser
```

Here is what I'd like to do: As a user, when a selection is done on the tree (and so the function "select" is called), I'd like my TreeUser to observe the events and do some treatments.
The fact is I am unable to get the Tree's events.

More generically, I'd like to be able to observe used components fired events. Is it possible with Ractive? If not, is there any workaround?

I have simplified my example. Consider everything works except this events observation.

**EDIT**:
When I say: "it does not work", I mean I get a javascript error:
`panel.components.Tree.observe is undefined`

But in the console of my debugger, `panel.components.Tree.prototype.observe`prints the code of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the `tree` instance of the component that was created and call observe on that. (btw `onrender` works, but IMO it makes more sense to use `oninit`)

```
onrender : function() {
    // use whatever tag alias you declared to "find" the component 
    this.findComponent('Tree').observe("selected", function(item){
        // Do something
    })
},
```

But, you don't really need an observer! The parent can directly subscribe to the component event using the same tag alias as an event prefix:

```
oninit: function() {
    this.on('Tree.selected', function(item){
        // will fire when component fires selected event!
    })
},
```